# How to retrieve data from two mysql tables using cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have two tables like as cats and games in mysql database. I have to retrieve all records from games table using CAKEPHP. Where cats table has tow fields id and name i.e category id and category name, where as games tables has some more fields including id, gname and category_id where cats.id is equal to games.category_id. How I fetch all data from games table including cats.name using cakephp where  cats.id is equal to games.category_id. I have created GamesController.php and two Model game.php & cat.php. Please help me

Comment: Read the documentation! http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html & http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html **everything** is there in great detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$join = 'joins' => array(
    array(
        'table' => 'categories',
        'alias' => 'Category',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Category.id = Game.category_id',
        ),
    ));

$this->Game->find('all',array(
                  "fields"=>array("Game.*","Category.*"),
                  "joins"=>$join)
                 );
```

Comment: Hi thanks, after little modification, its working fine, thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
$this->Name->find('all', array('games' => array('category_id' => $cat_id)));
```

or
$this->Name->query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE category_id= '$cats.id';");

and read [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) document

Comment: This is not how things work, the `games` key is of no use, and the `query()` example creates a nice SQL injection vulnerability.